# Xcode not compiling "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'"

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, uitableview

I'm having quite a problem trying to make a simple Table View in my iOS application. I started with a bit more complicated source code, but while tracking down the error I found out it was an error in the Table View Controller's Data Source Methods. So I made a very simple app with a simple Nav Controller and a Table View and I havent even managed to get it to run.

Here's what my code looks like:

AppDelegate.m

```
    #import "BIDAppDelegate.h"

    #import "BIDFirstLevelController.h"

    @implementation BIDAppDelegate

    @synthesize window = _window;
    @synthesize navController = _navController;

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        BIDFirstLevelController *firstView = [[BIDFirstLevelController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstView];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }
```

Here's the method that's causing trouble. To test it, I just want a list that displays 3 cells that say "Hello".

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";

        return cell;
    }
```

Xcode marks no errors before compiling, but when I try to do it, it shows this in the console and it doesn't compile my App.

```
     Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

Change this method to

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44) reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, sorry I'm kind of new in iOS development.